# Why two numbers not summarized in script?

Tags: bash, unix

I am newer in bash.
I try to create script that summarizetwo numbers:

Here is script:

```
echo "the result is:" expr $1+$2
```

Here how I call the script:

```
./scr3 50 98
```

And here is result that I get after the script executed:

```
the result is: expr 50+98
```

While I get the the string with two summarized numbers I expect to get the summarize of two numbers.

My question is why I don't get the result of summarize of the two numbers?

Comment: You aren't telling it to *run* `expr` here at all. You're passing `expr` as an *argument*. Arguments passed to `echo` are strings for it to print.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93030/62174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why? Because `echo` prints its arguments, and you're passing `expr` as an argument.

A best-practice alternative would be:

```
echo "The result is: $(( $1 + $2 ))"
```

...though the a smaller change (albeit to very inefficient code; `expr` is an artifact of the 1970s, made irrelevant with the introduction of `$(( ))` in the 1992 POSIX sh standard, and should never be used in new development) is simply:

```
echo "The result is: $( expr "$1" + "$2" )"
```